# Tagging a class with no Awakening weapon on release

Tags: black-desert-online

Since the new class, Sage will be released on EU / NA today and I have never tagged a character before, I was wondering the following:

1. Sage will release without an Awakening weapon - how does this affect tagging him?
2. Most likely he will receive his Awakening weapon later. Can I just tag the weapon when it's released or do I need to tag my whole gear again this time with his AWK Weapon?
3. How does not having an Awakening weapon affect his damage in Succession?

I'm playing on PC.

Comment: A lot of Players told me that a Succession class misses about 30% DMG without an AWK weapon. However, I am not sure if that is true in Sage's case. I asked in the Official BDO Discord and didn't get an answer on how the tagging will work once his AWK weapon will be released.

Comment: We just got confirmation that Sage's Succession has 100% DMG instead of 70%. His missing AWK weapon DMG was compansated by a Succession DMG buff by the BDO Devs. Sage's DMG will be nerfed once an AWK weapon will be released. Still no anser on how the tagging will work.

Comment: So apparently you would need to pay 10€ to tag your AWK weapon  or retag your entire gear. I personally have not tested this, but 2 players on Discord told me so. The information could be wrong that's why this is a comment and not an answer.